# Data sorting with R for XLConnect

Tags: r, xlconnect

Ok, so I have a workbook in Excel with sheets that look like this:

```
Date      1/2/15      1/3/15      1/4/15
Euro      3.54        2.50        #N/A  
USD       3.20        3.30        3.35
Yen       2.50        2.35        2.40
```

The sheets are arranged exactly like this. I loaded each sheet individually via XLConnect such that:

```
wbFX <- loadWorkbook("fx.xlsx")
FX.high <- readWorksheet(wbFX, sheet=1)
FX.low <- readWorksheet(wbFX, sheet=2)
FX.close <- readWorksheet(wbFX, sheet=3)
```

One sheet is for closing prices, the other for low and the last one is closing prices.

I want to merge the currency rows (i.e: grouping Euro low, Euro high, Euro close) and create a table or dataframe such that I have:

```
Date            1/2/15      1/3/15      1/4/15
Euro close      3.54        2.50        #N/A  
Euro low        3.20        3.30        3.35
Euro high       2.50        2.35        2.40
```

I only have very rudimentary knowledge of R and I'm not very familiar with the for() loop function in R. I understand the basics of it, but I'm struggling to reproduce what I want.

Suggestions would be very much appreciated!

UPDATED: Adding dput(FX.high) gives:

```
> dput(head(FX.high)) 
structure(list(Col1 = c("EUR CURNCY", "JPY CURNCY", "GBP CURNCY", 
"CHF CURNCY", "AUD CURNCY", "CAD CURNCY"), X2016.08.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1192, 
102.56, 1.312, 0.9815, 0.758, 1.3056), X2016.08.29.00.00.00 = c(1.1208, 
102.39, 1.3172, 0.9807, 0.7582, 1.3048), X2016.08.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1341, 
101.94, 1.3279, 0.9793, 0.7692, 1.3012), X2016.08.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1341, 
101.94, 1.3279, 0.9793, 0.7692, 1.3012), X2016.08.26.00.00.00 = c(1.1341, 
101.94, 1.3279, 0.9793, 0.7692, 1.3012), X2016.08.25.00.00.00 = c(1.1298, 
100.62, 1.3264, 0.9688, 0.7639, 1.294), X2016.08.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1312, 
100.61, 1.3273, 0.9684, 0.7634, 1.2958), X2016.08.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1355, 
100.39, 1.3211, 0.9634, 0.7655, 1.2948), X2016.08.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1334, 
100.93, 1.3157, 0.9649, 0.764, 1.2965), X2016.08.21.00.00.00 = c(1.136, 
100.46, 1.3185, 0.9611, 0.7691, 1.2892), X2016.08.20.00.00.00 = c(1.136, 
100.46, 1.3185, 0.9611, 0.7691, 1.2892), X2016.08.19.00.00.00 = c(1.136, 
100.46, 1.3185, 0.9611, 0.7691, 1.2892), X2016.08.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1366, 
100.5, 1.3173, 0.9627, 0.7723, 1.2858), X2016.08.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1316, 
101.17, 1.3086, 0.9659, 0.7708, 1.2918), X2016.08.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1323, 
101.29, 1.3051, 0.9735, 0.7749, 1.2934), X2016.08.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1204, 
101.45, 1.2945, 0.9775, 0.7692, 1.2976), X2016.08.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1221, 
102.27, 1.3035, 0.9766, 0.7725, 1.2994), X2016.08.13.00.00.00 = c(1.1221, 
102.27, 1.3035, 0.9766, 0.7725, 1.2994), X2016.08.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1221, 
102.27, 1.3035, 0.9766, 0.7725, 1.2994), X2016.08.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1192, 
102.06, 1.3028, 0.9766, 0.775, 1.308), X2016.08.10.00.00.00 = c(1.119, 
101.96, 1.3094, 0.9819, 0.7756, 1.3124), X2016.08.09.00.00.00 = c(1.1123, 
102.53, 1.3049, 0.9844, 0.7687, 1.319), X2016.08.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1105, 
102.66, 1.3097, 0.9842, 0.7672, 1.319), X2016.08.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1161, 
102.06, 1.3175, 0.9831, 0.7664, 1.32), X2016.08.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1161, 
102.06, 1.3175, 0.9831, 0.7664, 1.32), X2016.08.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1161, 
102.06, 1.3175, 0.9831, 0.7664, 1.32), X2016.08.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1156, 
101.67, 1.3346, 0.975, 0.7641, 1.3089), X2016.08.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1227, 
101.57, 1.3372, 0.9739, 0.7616, 1.3148), X2016.08.02.00.00.00 = c(1.1234, 
102.83, 1.3366, 0.9698, 0.7638, 1.3142), X2016.08.01.00.00.00 = c(1.1184, 
102.68, 1.3273, 0.9703, 0.7615, 1.3127), X2016.07.31.00.00.00 = c(1.1197, 
105.63, 1.3301, 0.981, 0.761, 1.3186), X2016.07.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1197, 
105.63, 1.3301, 0.981, 0.761, 1.3186), X2016.07.29.00.00.00 = c(1.1197, 
105.63, 1.3301, 0.981, 0.761, 1.3186), X2016.07.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1119, 
105.51, 1.3248, 0.9868, 0.7549, 1.3192), X2016.07.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1065, 
106.54, 1.3235, 0.995, 0.7566, 1.3253), X2016.07.26.00.00.00 = c(1.103, 
105.89, 1.3176, 0.9928, 0.754, 1.3244), X2016.07.25.00.00.00 = c(1.0999, 
106.72, 1.3165, 0.9897, 0.7492, 1.3242), X2016.07.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1041, 
106.4, 1.3291, 0.9895, 0.7508, 1.3185), X2016.07.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1041, 
106.4, 1.3291, 0.9895, 0.7508, 1.3185), X2016.07.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1041, 
106.4, 1.3291, 0.9895, 0.7508, 1.3185), X2016.07.21.00.00.00 = c(1.106, 
107.49, 1.3275, 0.9907, 0.7514, 1.3101), X2016.07.20.00.00.00 = c(1.103, 
107.02, 1.3226, 0.9905, 0.7517, 1.3096), X2016.07.19.00.00.00 = c(1.1081, 
106.53, 1.3276, 0.9878, 0.7592, 1.3054), X2016.07.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1084, 
106.26, 1.3315, 0.9847, 0.7607, 1.3022), X2016.07.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1149, 
106.32, 1.3481, 0.9847, 0.7676, 1.2988), X2016.07.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1149, 
106.32, 1.3481, 0.9847, 0.7676, 1.2988), X2016.07.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1149, 
106.32, 1.3481, 0.9847, 0.7676, 1.2988), X2016.07.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1165, 
105.94, 1.3475, 0.9854, 0.7653, 1.2987), X2016.07.13.00.00.00 = c(1.112, 
104.88, 1.3338, 0.9894, 0.7638, 1.3084), X2016.07.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1126, 
104.99, 1.3295, 0.9894, 0.7658, 1.3133), X2016.07.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1075, 
102.89, 1.3018, 0.9858, 0.7576, 1.314), X2016.07.10.00.00.00 = c(1.112, 
101.28, 1.3019, 0.9866, 0.7574, 1.309), X2016.07.09.00.00.00 = c(1.112, 
101.28, 1.3019, 0.9866, 0.7574, 1.309), X2016.07.08.00.00.00 = c(1.112, 
101.28, 1.3019, 0.9866, 0.7574, 1.309), X2016.07.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1107, 
101.41, 1.3047, 0.9792, 0.7539, 1.3021), X2016.07.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1112, 
101.77, 1.3028, 0.9806, 0.7529, 1.3056), X2016.07.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1186, 
102.59, 1.3291, 0.9774, 0.7545, 1.3017), X2016.07.04.00.00.00 = c(1.116, 
102.8, 1.3341, 0.9759, 0.7545, 1.2926), X2016.07.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1169, 
103.39, 1.335, 0.9781, 0.7503, 1.2975), X2016.07.02.00.00.00 = c(1.1169, 
103.39, 1.335, 0.9781, 0.7503, 1.2975), X2016.07.01.00.00.00 = c(1.1169, 
103.39, 1.335, 0.9781, 0.7503, 1.2975), X2016.06.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1155, 
103.29, 1.3496, 0.9821, 0.7473, 1.3016), X2016.06.29.00.00.00 = c(1.113, 
102.94, 1.3534, 0.9823, 0.7456, 1.3042), X2016.06.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1112, 
102.84, 1.3419, 0.9837, 0.7415, 1.3108), X2016.06.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1084, 
102.48, 1.3566, 0.9819, 0.7459, 1.312), X2016.06.26.00.00.00 = c(1.1428, 
106.84, 1.5018, 0.9804, 0.7648, 1.3099), X2016.06.25.00.00.00 = c(1.1428, 
106.84, 1.5018, 0.9804, 0.7648, 1.3099), X2016.06.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1428, 
106.84, 1.5018, 0.9804, 0.7648, 1.3099), X2016.06.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1421, 
106.17, 1.4947, 0.9602, 0.7616, 1.2847), X2016.06.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1338, 
104.85, 1.4774, 0.9629, 0.7527, 1.2853), X2016.06.21.00.00.00 = c(1.135, 
105.06, 1.4783, 0.9624, 0.7513, 1.2827), X2016.06.20.00.00.00 = c(1.1382, 
104.85, 1.472, 0.9643, 0.7481, 1.2889), X2016.06.19.00.00.00 = c(1.1296, 
104.83, 1.4388, 0.9659, 0.7411, 1.2968), X2016.06.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1296, 
104.83, 1.4388, 0.9659, 0.7411, 1.2968), X2016.06.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1296, 
104.83, 1.4388, 0.9659, 0.7411, 1.2968), X2016.06.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1295, 
106.03, 1.4254, 0.9687, 0.744, 1.3086), X2016.06.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1298, 
106.4, 1.4218, 0.9664, 0.7446, 1.2943), X2016.06.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1298, 
106.42, 1.4271, 0.9669, 0.7405, 1.2873), X2016.06.13.00.00.00 = c(1.1303, 
106.98, 1.4328, 0.9679, 0.7411, 1.2839), X2016.06.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1321, 
107.26, 1.4473, 0.9658, 0.7438, 1.2784), X2016.06.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1321, 
107.26, 1.4473, 0.9658, 0.7438, 1.2784), X2016.06.10.00.00.00 = c(1.1321, 
107.26, 1.4473, 0.9658, 0.7438, 1.2784), X2016.06.09.00.00.00 = c(1.1416, 
107.18, 1.4527, 0.9656, 0.7505, 1.2767), X2016.06.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1411, 
107.39, 1.4601, 0.9659, 0.7482, 1.2761), X2016.06.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1381, 
107.9, 1.466, 0.9719, 0.7464, 1.284), X2016.06.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1393, 
107.66, 1.4529, 0.978, 0.7391, 1.2983), X2016.06.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1374, 
109.14, 1.4582, 0.992, 0.7369, 1.3107), X2016.06.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1374, 
109.14, 1.4582, 0.992, 0.7369, 1.3107), X2016.06.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1374, 
109.14, 1.4582, 0.992, 0.7369, 1.3107), X2016.06.02.00.00.00 = c(1.122, 
109.59, 1.4473, 0.9911, 0.727, 1.3144), X2016.06.01.00.00.00 = c(1.1194, 
110.83, 1.4508, 0.9951, 0.7299, 1.3123), X2016.05.31.00.00.00 = c(1.1173, 
111.35, 1.4725, 0.9951, 0.7267, 1.3134), X2016.05.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1145, 
111.45, 1.4642, 0.9956, 0.7188, 1.3095), X2016.05.29.00.00.00 = c(1.1201, 
110.45, 1.4689, 0.9949, 0.7235, 1.3068), X2016.05.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1201, 
110.45, 1.4689, 0.9949, 0.7235, 1.3068), X2016.05.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1201, 
110.45, 1.4689, 0.9949, 0.7235, 1.3068), X2016.05.26.00.00.00 = c(1.1217, 
110.23, 1.474, 0.9928, 0.7244, 1.3037), X2016.05.25.00.00.00 = c(1.1167, 
110.45, 1.4729, 0.9936, 0.7219, 1.3133), X2016.05.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1227, 
110.13, 1.4642, 0.9938, 0.7228, 1.3188), X2016.05.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1243, 
110.24, 1.4549, 0.9924, 0.726, 1.3174), X2016.05.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1237, 
110.59, 1.4613, 0.9927, 0.725, 1.3162), X2016.05.21.00.00.00 = c(1.1237, 
110.59, 1.4613, 0.9927, 0.725, 1.3162), X2016.05.20.00.00.00 = c(1.1237, 
110.59, 1.4613, 0.9927, 0.725, 1.3162), X2016.05.19.00.00.00 = c(1.123, 
110.38, 1.4663, 0.9923, 0.7242, 1.3154), X2016.05.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1316, 
110.26, 1.4635, 0.9881, 0.7332, 1.3037), X2016.05.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1349, 
109.65, 1.4524, 0.9809, 0.7366, 1.2955), X2016.05.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1342, 
109.1, 1.4415, 0.9784, 0.7309, 1.2963), X2016.05.15.00.00.00 = c(1.138, 
109.56, 1.4456, 0.9775, 0.7326, 1.2958), X2016.05.14.00.00.00 = c(1.138, 
109.56, 1.4456, 0.9775, 0.7326, 1.2958), X2016.05.13.00.00.00 = c(1.138, 
109.56, 1.4456, 0.9775, 0.7326, 1.2958), X2016.05.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1429, 
109.4, 1.4531, 0.9726, 0.738, 1.2879), X2016.05.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1447, 
109.38, 1.4488, 0.9762, 0.7402, 1.2942), X2016.05.10.00.00.00 = c(1.141, 
109.35, 1.4478, 0.9763, 0.7374, 1.298), X2016.05.09.00.00.00 = c(1.142, 
108.6, 1.448, 0.9736, 0.7385, 1.3015), X2016.05.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1479, 
107.42, 1.4543, 0.973, 0.7478, 1.2952), X2016.05.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1479, 
107.42, 1.4543, 0.973, 0.7478, 1.2952), X2016.05.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1479, 
107.42, 1.4543, 0.973, 0.7478, 1.2952), X2016.05.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1494, 
107.5, 1.4529, 0.9697, 0.7514, 1.2875), X2016.05.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1529, 
107.46, 1.4572, 0.959, 0.7517, 1.2886), X2016.05.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1616, 
106.68, 1.477, 0.9554, 0.7719, 1.2732), X2016.05.02.00.00.00 = c(1.1536, 
106.82, 1.4696, 0.9605, 0.7672, 1.2571), X2016.05.01.00.00.00 = c(1.1459, 
108.2, 1.467, 0.9672, 0.7669, 1.2587), X2016.04.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1459, 
108.2, 1.467, 0.9672, 0.7669, 1.2587), X2016.04.29.00.00.00 = c(1.1459, 
108.2, 1.467, 0.9672, 0.7669, 1.2587), X2016.04.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1368, 
111.88, 1.4623, 0.9734, 0.7658, 1.2606), X2016.04.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1362, 
111.75, 1.4622, 0.9753, 0.7765, 1.2694), X2016.04.26.00.00.00 = c(1.134, 
111.47, 1.4639, 0.9767, 0.7765, 1.2688), X2016.04.25.00.00.00 = c(1.1278, 
111.91, 1.452, 0.9794, 0.7729, 1.2717), X2016.04.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1309, 
111.81, 1.4452, 0.9797, 0.7774, 1.2758), X2016.04.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1309, 
111.81, 1.4452, 0.9797, 0.7774, 1.2758), X2016.04.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1309, 
111.81, 1.4452, 0.9797, 0.7774, 1.2758), X2016.04.21.00.00.00 = c(1.1398, 
109.9, 1.444, 0.9753, 0.7835, 1.275), X2016.04.20.00.00.00 = c(1.1388, 
109.88, 1.441, 0.9733, 0.7829, 1.273), X2016.04.19.00.00.00 = c(1.1385, 
109.49, 1.4419, 0.965, 0.7826, 1.2798), X2016.04.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1332, 
108.99, 1.4291, 0.9679, 0.7759, 1.299), X2016.04.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1317, 
109.73, 1.4242, 0.9688, 0.7734, 1.2903), X2016.04.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1317, 
109.73, 1.4242, 0.9688, 0.7734, 1.2903), X2016.04.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1317, 
109.73, 1.4242, 0.9688, 0.7734, 1.2903), X2016.04.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1295, 
109.55, 1.4208, 0.9688, 0.7737, 1.2897), X2016.04.13.00.00.00 = c(1.1391, 
109.41, 1.4279, 0.9672, 0.7716, 1.2828), X2016.04.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1465, 
108.79, 1.4348, 0.9594, 0.769, 1.2921), X2016.04.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1447, 
108.44, 1.4287, 0.9571, 0.763, 1.3016), X2016.04.10.00.00.00 = c(1.1419, 
109.1, 1.4141, 0.9582, 0.7579, 1.3157), X2016.04.09.00.00.00 = c(1.1419, 
109.1, 1.4141, 0.9582, 0.7579, 1.3157), X2016.04.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1419, 
109.1, 1.4141, 0.9582, 0.7579, 1.3157), X2016.04.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1454, 
109.9, 1.4157, 0.9581, 0.7637, 1.3181), X2016.04.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1432, 
110.64, 1.4171, 0.9622, 0.7619, 1.3187), X2016.04.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1405, 
111.36, 1.4279, 0.9605, 0.7632, 1.3219), X2016.04.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1413, 
111.8, 1.4322, 0.9615, 0.7679, 1.3088), X2016.04.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1438, 
112.58, 1.4372, 0.9626, 0.7701, 1.3147), X2016.04.02.00.00.00 = c(1.1438, 
112.58, 1.4372, 0.9626, 0.7701, 1.3147), X2016.04.01.00.00.00 = c(1.1438, 
112.58, 1.4372, 0.9626, 0.7701, 1.3147), X2016.03.31.00.00.00 = c(1.1412, 
112.66, 1.4426, 0.9663, 0.7723, 1.3011), X2016.03.30.00.00.00 = c(1.1365, 
112.81, 1.4459, 0.9672, 0.7709, 1.3081), X2016.03.29.00.00.00 = c(1.1303, 
113.8, 1.4404, 0.9763, 0.7645, 1.3216), X2016.03.28.00.00.00 = c(1.122, 
113.69, 1.4283, 0.9787, 0.7558, 1.3285), X2016.03.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1181, 
113.32, 1.4159, 0.9788, 0.7535, 1.3285), X2016.03.26.00.00.00 = c(1.1181, 
113.32, 1.4159, 0.9788, 0.7535, 1.3285), X2016.03.25.00.00.00 = c(1.1181, 
113.32, 1.4159, 0.9788, 0.7535, 1.3285), X2016.03.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1188, 
113.01, 1.4183, 0.9774, 0.7538, 1.3296), X2016.03.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1224, 
112.91, 1.4227, 0.9766, 0.7649, 1.3219), X2016.03.22.00.00.00 = c(1.126, 
112.49, 1.4398, 0.9736, 0.7643, 1.3139), X2016.03.21.00.00.00 = c(1.1288, 
111.98, 1.4469, 0.9731, 0.7627, 1.3102), X2016.03.20.00.00.00 = c(1.1337, 
111.76, 1.4514, 0.9717, 0.768, 1.3043), X2016.03.19.00.00.00 = c(1.1337, 
111.76, 1.4514, 0.9717, 0.768, 1.3043), X2016.03.18.00.00.00 = c(1.1337, 
111.76, 1.4514, 0.9717, 0.768, 1.3043), X2016.03.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1342, 
112.96, 1.4503, 0.9787, 0.7657, 1.3133), X2016.03.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1242, 
113.82, 1.4274, 0.9914, 0.7561, 1.3405), X2016.03.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1125, 
114.14, 1.4306, 0.9896, 0.7528, 1.3402), X2016.03.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1176, 
114.01, 1.4401, 0.9882, 0.7594, 1.3308), X2016.03.13.00.00.00 = c(1.121, 
113.92, 1.4437, 0.9891, 0.7584, 1.3359), X2016.03.12.00.00.00 = c(1.121, 
113.92, 1.4437, 0.9891, 0.7584, 1.3359), X2016.03.11.00.00.00 = c(1.121, 
113.92, 1.4437, 0.9891, 0.7584, 1.3359), X2016.03.10.00.00.00 = c(1.1218, 
114.45, 1.4317, 1.0093, 0.7512, 1.3398), X2016.03.09.00.00.00 = c(1.1035, 
113.45, 1.4241, 1.0039, 0.7528, 1.3446), X2016.03.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1058, 
113.52, 1.4276, 0.9971, 0.7473, 1.3425), X2016.03.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1026, 
114.09, 1.4284, 1.0012, 0.7485, 1.3377), X2016.03.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1043, 
114.26, 1.4248, 0.9989, 0.7443, 1.3471), X2016.03.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1043, 
114.26, 1.4248, 0.9989, 0.7443, 1.3471), X2016.03.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1043, 
114.26, 1.4248, 0.9989, 0.7443, 1.3471), X2016.03.03.00.00.00 = c(1.0973, 
114.27, 1.4194, 0.9983, 0.7374, 1.3473), X2016.03.02.00.00.00 = c(1.0881, 
114.56, 1.4093, 1.0009, 0.7301, 1.3499), X2016.03.01.00.00.00 = c(1.0894, 
114.19, 1.4018, 1.0009, 0.7192, 1.3552), X2016.02.29.00.00.00 = c(1.0963, 
113.99, 1.3946, 1.0038, 0.7168, 1.3587), X2016.02.28.00.00.00 = c(1.1068, 
114, 1.4043, 0.9989, 0.7257, 1.3565), X2016.02.27.00.00.00 = c(1.1068, 
114, 1.4043, 0.9989, 0.7257, 1.3565), X2016.02.26.00.00.00 = c(1.1068, 
114, 1.4043, 0.9989, 0.7257, 1.3565), X2016.02.25.00.00.00 = c(1.105, 
113.02, 1.3997, 0.9952, 0.7244, 1.3735), X2016.02.24.00.00.00 = c(1.1046, 
112.27, 1.4028, 0.9953, 0.7213, 1.3859), X2016.02.23.00.00.00 = c(1.1053, 
113.05, 1.4156, 1.0002, 0.7259, 1.3821), X2016.02.22.00.00.00 = c(1.1135, 
113.39, 1.4332, 1.0004, 0.7247, 1.3813), X2016.02.21.00.00.00 = c(1.1139, 
113.38, 1.4409, 0.9968, 0.7162, 1.3847), X2016.02.20.00.00.00 = c(1.1139, 
113.38, 1.4409, 0.9968, 0.7162, 1.3847), X2016.02.19.00.00.00 = c(1.1139, 
113.38, 1.4409, 0.9968, 0.7162, 1.3847), X2016.02.18.00.00.00 = c(1.115, 
114.33, 1.4394, 0.9969, 0.7185, 1.3752), X2016.02.17.00.00.00 = c(1.1179, 
114.51, 1.4339, 0.9942, 0.7187, 1.3899), X2016.02.16.00.00.00 = c(1.1193, 
114.87, 1.4516, 0.9896, 0.7182, 1.3912), X2016.02.15.00.00.00 = c(1.1261, 
114.73, 1.4567, 0.9889, 0.7172, 1.3867), X2016.02.14.00.00.00 = c(1.1334, 
113.54, 1.457, 0.9791, 0.7129, 1.3965), X2016.02.13.00.00.00 = c(1.1334, 
113.54, 1.457, 0.9791, 0.7129, 1.3965), X2016.02.12.00.00.00 = c(1.1334, 
113.54, 1.457, 0.9791, 0.7129, 1.3965), X2016.02.11.00.00.00 = c(1.1376, 
113.6, 1.4564, 0.9762, 0.7153, 1.4016), X2016.02.10.00.00.00 = c(1.1311, 
115.26, 1.4578, 0.982, 0.7125, 1.3999), X2016.02.09.00.00.00 = c(1.1338, 
115.85, 1.4516, 0.9875, 0.7096, 1.396), X2016.02.08.00.00.00 = c(1.1216, 
117.53, 1.4547, 0.9973, 0.7129, 1.3978), X2016.02.07.00.00.00 = c(1.1246, 
117.43, 1.4592, 0.9985, 0.7219, 1.3919), X2016.02.06.00.00.00 = c(1.1246, 
117.43, 1.4592, 0.9985, 0.7219, 1.3919), X2016.02.05.00.00.00 = c(1.1246, 
117.43, 1.4592, 0.9985, 0.7219, 1.3919), X2016.02.04.00.00.00 = c(1.1239, 
118.24, 1.4668, 1.0074, 0.7243, 1.3798), X2016.02.03.00.00.00 = c(1.1146, 
120.04, 1.4649, 1.0196, 0.7189, 1.4103), X2016.02.02.00.00.00 = c(1.094, 
121.04, 1.4446, 1.0224, 0.7129, 1.4082), X2016.02.01.00.00.00 = c(1.0913, 
121.49, 1.4445, 1.025, 0.7121, 1.4062), X2016.01.31.00.00.00 = c(1.0949, 
121.69, 1.4413, 1.0257, 0.7141, 1.4109), X2016.01.30.00.00.00 = c(1.0949, 
121.69, 1.4413, 1.0257, 0.7141, 1.4109), X2016.01.29.00.00.00 = c(1.0949, 
121.69, 1.4413, 1.0257, 0.7141, 1.4109), X2016.01.28.00.00.00 = c(1.0968, 
118.99, 1.4408, 1.0178, 0.7129, 1.4123), X2016.01.27.00.00.00 = c(1.0917, 
119.07, 1.4355, 1.0189, 0.7082, 1.4157), X2016.01.26.00.00.00 = c(1.0874, 
118.62, 1.4367, 1.0199, 0.7021, 1.4326), X2016.01.25.00.00.00 = c(1.0857, 
118.86, 1.4332, 1.0184, 0.7032, 1.4293), X2016.01.24.00.00.00 = c(1.0877, 
118.88, 1.4363, 1.0166, 0.7046, 1.4301), X2016.01.23.00.00.00 = c(1.0877, 
118.88, 1.4363, 1.0166, 0.7046, 1.4301), X2016.01.22.00.00.00 = c(1.0877, 
118.88, 1.4363, 1.0166, 0.7046, 1.4301), X2016.01.21.00.00.00 = c(1.0921, 
117.81, 1.4249, 1.0147, 0.7018, 1.4541), X2016.01.20.00.00.00 = c(1.0976, 
117.69, 1.4219, 1.0058, 0.6926, 1.469), X2016.01.19.00.00.00 = c(1.0939, 
118.11, 1.434, 1.0082, 0.6957, 1.4589), X2016.01.18.00.00.00 = c(1.0942, 
117.44, 1.4323, 1.0073, 0.6928, 1.466), X2016.01.17.00.00.00 = c(1.0985, 
118.27, 1.4428, 1.0061, 0.7002, 1.4554), X2016.01.16.00.00.00 = c(1.0985, 
118.27, 1.4428, 1.0061, 0.7002, 1.4554), X2016.01.15.00.00.00 = c(1.0985, 
118.27, 1.4428, 1.0061, 0.7002, 1.4554), X2016.01.14.00.00.00 = c(1.0943, 
118.28, 1.4445, 1.0092, 0.6997, 1.4397), X2016.01.13.00.00.00 = c(1.0888, 
118.38, 1.4476, 1.0107, 0.7049, 1.438), X2016.01.12.00.00.00 = c(1.09, 
118.07, 1.456, 1.0047, 0.7021, 1.4315), X2016.01.11.00.00.00 = c(1.097, 
118.02, 1.4604, 1.0023, 0.7036, 1.4246), X2016.01.10.00.00.00 = c(1.0934, 
118.83, 1.4645, 1.0052, 0.7077, 1.4178), X2016.01.09.00.00.00 = c(1.0934, 
118.83, 1.4645, 1.0052, 0.7077, 1.4178), X2016.01.08.00.00.00 = c(1.0934, 
118.83, 1.4645, 1.0052, 0.7077, 1.4178), X2016.01.07.00.00.00 = c(1.094, 
118.76, 1.4641, 1.0081, 0.7086, 1.417), X2016.01.06.00.00.00 = c(1.0799, 
119.17, 1.4682, 1.0121, 0.7172, 1.4109), X2016.01.05.00.00.00 = c(1.0839, 
119.7, 1.4726, 1.0125, 0.7215, 1.4019), X2016.01.04.00.00.00 = c(1.0946, 
120.47, 1.4816, 1.0063, 0.7305, 1.3983), X2016.01.03.00.00.00 = c(1.0867, 
120.55, 1.476, 1.0083, 0.7304, 1.3856), X2016.01.02.00.00.00 = c(1.0867, 
120.55, 1.476, 1.0083, 0.7304, 1.3856), X2016.01.01.00.00.00 = c(1.0867, 
120.55, 1.476, 1.0083, 0.7304, 1.3856)), .Names = c("Col1", "X2016.08.30.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.29.00.00.00", "X2016.08.28.00.00.00", "X2016.08.27.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.26.00.00.00", "X2016.08.25.00.00.00", "X2016.08.24.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.23.00.00.00", "X2016.08.22.00.00.00", "X2016.08.21.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.20.00.00.00", "X2016.08.19.00.00.00", "X2016.08.18.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.17.00.00.00", "X2016.08.16.00.00.00", "X2016.08.15.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.14.00.00.00", "X2016.08.13.00.00.00", "X2016.08.12.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.11.00.00.00", "X2016.08.10.00.00.00", "X2016.08.09.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.08.00.00.00", "X2016.08.07.00.00.00", "X2016.08.06.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.05.00.00.00", "X2016.08.04.00.00.00", "X2016.08.03.00.00.00", 
"X2016.08.02.00.00.00", "X2016.08.01.00.00.00", "X2016.07.31.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.30.00.00.00", "X2016.07.29.00.00.00", "X2016.07.28.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.27.00.00.00", "X2016.07.26.00.00.00", "X2016.07.25.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.24.00.00.00", "X2016.07.23.00.00.00", "X2016.07.22.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.21.00.00.00", "X2016.07.20.00.00.00", "X2016.07.19.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.18.00.00.00", "X2016.07.17.00.00.00", "X2016.07.16.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.15.00.00.00", "X2016.07.14.00.00.00", "X2016.07.13.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.12.00.00.00", "X2016.07.11.00.00.00", "X2016.07.10.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.09.00.00.00", "X2016.07.08.00.00.00", "X2016.07.07.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.06.00.00.00", "X2016.07.05.00.00.00", "X2016.07.04.00.00.00", 
"X2016.07.03.00.00.00", "X2016.07.02.00.00.00", "X2016.07.01.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.30.00.00.00", "X2016.06.29.00.00.00", "X2016.06.28.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.27.00.00.00", "X2016.06.26.00.00.00", "X2016.06.25.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.24.00.00.00", "X2016.06.23.00.00.00", "X2016.06.22.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.21.00.00.00", "X2016.06.20.00.00.00", "X2016.06.19.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.18.00.00.00", "X2016.06.17.00.00.00", "X2016.06.16.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.15.00.00.00", "X2016.06.14.00.00.00", "X2016.06.13.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.12.00.00.00", "X2016.06.11.00.00.00", "X2016.06.10.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.09.00.00.00", "X2016.06.08.00.00.00", "X2016.06.07.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.06.00.00.00", "X2016.06.05.00.00.00", "X2016.06.04.00.00.00", 
"X2016.06.03.00.00.00", "X2016.06.02.00.00.00", "X2016.06.01.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.31.00.00.00", "X2016.05.30.00.00.00", "X2016.05.29.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.28.00.00.00", "X2016.05.27.00.00.00", "X2016.05.26.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.25.00.00.00", "X2016.05.24.00.00.00", "X2016.05.23.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.22.00.00.00", "X2016.05.21.00.00.00", "X2016.05.20.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.19.00.00.00", "X2016.05.18.00.00.00", "X2016.05.17.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.16.00.00.00", "X2016.05.15.00.00.00", "X2016.05.14.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.13.00.00.00", "X2016.05.12.00.00.00", "X2016.05.11.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.10.00.00.00", "X2016.05.09.00.00.00", "X2016.05.08.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.07.00.00.00", "X2016.05.06.00.00.00", "X2016.05.05.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.04.00.00.00", "X2016.05.03.00.00.00", "X2016.05.02.00.00.00", 
"X2016.05.01.00.00.00", "X2016.04.30.00.00.00", "X2016.04.29.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.28.00.00.00", "X2016.04.27.00.00.00", "X2016.04.26.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.25.00.00.00", "X2016.04.24.00.00.00", "X2016.04.23.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.22.00.00.00", "X2016.04.21.00.00.00", "X2016.04.20.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.19.00.00.00", "X2016.04.18.00.00.00", "X2016.04.17.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.16.00.00.00", "X2016.04.15.00.00.00", "X2016.04.14.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.13.00.00.00", "X2016.04.12.00.00.00", "X2016.04.11.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.10.00.00.00", "X2016.04.09.00.00.00", "X2016.04.08.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.07.00.00.00", "X2016.04.06.00.00.00", "X2016.04.05.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.04.00.00.00", "X2016.04.03.00.00.00", "X2016.04.02.00.00.00", 
"X2016.04.01.00.00.00", "X2016.03.31.00.00.00", "X2016.03.30.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.29.00.00.00", "X2016.03.28.00.00.00", "X2016.03.27.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.26.00.00.00", "X2016.03.25.00.00.00", "X2016.03.24.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.23.00.00.00", "X2016.03.22.00.00.00", "X2016.03.21.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.20.00.00.00", "X2016.03.19.00.00.00", "X2016.03.18.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.17.00.00.00", "X2016.03.16.00.00.00", "X2016.03.15.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.14.00.00.00", "X2016.03.13.00.00.00", "X2016.03.12.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.11.00.00.00", "X2016.03.10.00.00.00", "X2016.03.09.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.08.00.00.00", "X2016.03.07.00.00.00", "X2016.03.06.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.05.00.00.00", "X2016.03.04.00.00.00", "X2016.03.03.00.00.00", 
"X2016.03.02.00.00.00", "X2016.03.01.00.00.00", "X2016.02.29.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.28.00.00.00", "X2016.02.27.00.00.00", "X2016.02.26.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.25.00.00.00", "X2016.02.24.00.00.00", "X2016.02.23.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.22.00.00.00", "X2016.02.21.00.00.00", "X2016.02.20.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.19.00.00.00", "X2016.02.18.00.00.00", "X2016.02.17.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.16.00.00.00", "X2016.02.15.00.00.00", "X2016.02.14.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.13.00.00.00", "X2016.02.12.00.00.00", "X2016.02.11.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.10.00.00.00", "X2016.02.09.00.00.00", "X2016.02.08.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.07.00.00.00", "X2016.02.06.00.00.00", "X2016.02.05.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.04.00.00.00", "X2016.02.03.00.00.00", "X2016.02.02.00.00.00", 
"X2016.02.01.00.00.00", "X2016.01.31.00.00.00", "X2016.01.30.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.29.00.00.00", "X2016.01.28.00.00.00", "X2016.01.27.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.26.00.00.00", "X2016.01.25.00.00.00", "X2016.01.24.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.23.00.00.00", "X2016.01.22.00.00.00", "X2016.01.21.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.20.00.00.00", "X2016.01.19.00.00.00", "X2016.01.18.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.17.00.00.00", "X2016.01.16.00.00.00", "X2016.01.15.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.14.00.00.00", "X2016.01.13.00.00.00", "X2016.01.12.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.11.00.00.00", "X2016.01.10.00.00.00", "X2016.01.09.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.08.00.00.00", "X2016.01.07.00.00.00", "X2016.01.06.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.05.00.00.00", "X2016.01.04.00.00.00", "X2016.01.03.00.00.00", 
"X2016.01.02.00.00.00", "X2016.01.01.00.00.00"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, since I don't have your data files, so let me know if the code below gives you what you wanted. The steps are as follows:

1. Get the names of the three worksheets in the Excel workbook (I'm assuming they'll be something like "close", "low", and "high").
2. Read each worksheet into a list of data frames using `lapply`. The data in your worksheets is transposed (i.e., the variables are in rows instead of columns), so we we transpose the data so that each variable is in a column, and we also add an extra column that tells us which worksheet the data originally came from.
3. Combine the three data frames into a single data frame.
4. "melt" so that the three different currencies will be stacked in long format.

The final output, `df`, should be a data frame in "long" format that's ready for analysis.

```
library(reshape2)
library(XLConnect)

wbFX <- loadWorkbook("fx.xlsx")

# Get names of worksheets
sheets = getSheets(wbFX)

# Read the three worksheets into a list of data frames
df = lapply(sheets, function(sh) {
  dat = as.data.frame(t(readWorksheet(wbFX, sheet=sh)))
  dat$Date = as.Date(dat$Date)
  dat$Price_Type = sh
  dat
})

# Combine each list element into a single data frame
df = do.call(rbind, df)

# Melt to long format
df = melt(df, id.var=c("Date", "Price_Type"), variable.name="Currency", value.name="Price")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried out the line of code, but I'm getting an error saying " Error in as.Date.default(dat$Date) : 
  do not know how to convert 'dat$Date' to class “Date”". I would like to change dat$Date so that it recognizes the first column of all sheets as date (i.e:  x[,i] = as.Date(x[,i], "%m/%d/%Y", where x is the worksheet.

Comment: Given the format of your data, it looks like I should have written, `as.Date(dat$Date, format="%m/%d/%y")` if that doesn't work, you'll need to tweak the format argument to match the actual structure of your dates. You should probably also add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! as.Date(dat$Date, format="%m/%d/%y") as well as the stringsAsFactors argument still doesn't seem to work. I'll try playing around with it. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
library(reshape2)
lst <- lapply(list(high, low, close), melt, id.vars = 1, variable.name = "var")
df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("Date", "var")), lst )
names(df) <- c("currency", "date", "high", "low", "close")
recast(df, currency+variable~date, id.var = 1:2)
```

which should give you something like

```
#  currency variable 1/2/15 1/3/15 1/4/15
# 1     Euro     high   ...   ...     ...
# 2     Euro      low   ...   ...     ...
# 3     Euro    close   ...   ...     ...
```

Comment: Thanks this would be exactly what I want! I'm trying to make this work but I'm getting an error saying "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column". I tried changing the line to:

df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("Date", "FX.high", "FX.low", "FX.close")), lst ).

But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Add `dput(head(FX.high))` to your post. (And the other data frames, if they got a different structure).

Comment: sorry for constantly messaging you, but changing it to Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("Date", "FX.low", "FX.high", "FX.close")), dput(head(FX.high, FX.close, FX.low)),  lst ) gives me "Error: length(n) == 1L is not TRUE"

Comment: No problem. "Add dput(head(FX.high)) to your post." asks you to edit your original post and add the result of the dput command to the post, so that one can see how your data looks like.

Comment: Oh how silly of me. Edited the post, thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add the original `dput(head(FX.high))` instead? Reason beeing: one can just do `FX.high <- ...yourdput...` and has a copy of your original data. It does not work with your edit.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry about that, and thanks for the patience

Comment: Thanks. It works just fine. For the sake of simplicity, I did `low <- close <- high <- FX.high` (where `FX.high` is your dput). So each one will be the same, but you can of course change that. And then I used `df <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c("Col1", "var")), lst )`. So `Col1` instead of `Date`.